# Update is failing after migrated to WildFly 8.2.0

Tags: jsf, wildfly, seam

We have migrated our application from JBoss 5.1.0 GA to WildFly 8.2.0, to achieve this we have upgraded our technologies to below versions.

```
JBoss Seam 2.2.0 to Seam 2.3.1
Hibernate 3.3.0 to 4.0.1
JSF 1.2 to 2.1
```

We are able to load all the pages and save the data successfully. But we are not able to update the data when we are using EntityHome.

I am using h:commandButton for saving the data

```
<h:commandButton id="save" 
                 styleClass="button" 
                      value="Save" 
                     action="#{userDetailMgr.doPersist}"
                   rendered="#{!userDetailHome.managed}"/>  

        <h:commandButton id="update" 
                 styleClass="button" 
                      value="Save" 
                     action="#{userDetailMgr.doUpdate}"
                   rendered="#{userDetailHome.managed}"/>
```

And the userDetailHome is as below

```
@Name("userDetailHome")
public class UserDetailHome extends
  EntityHome<UserDetailHome> {
 //Override the isManaged() method to identify the results
 @Override
public boolean isManaged() {
System.out.println("Managed Value " + super.isManaged());
return super.isManaged();
}
}
```

And userDetailMgr is as below

```
@Name("userDetailMgr")
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
public class UserDetailMgr extends AbstractManager
implements Serializable {
@In
EntityManager entityManager;
public String doUpdate() {
userDetailHome.update();
}
public String doPersist() {
userDetailHome.persist();
}
}
```

Based on sysout in UserDetailHome isManaged() I observed that while loading   the page we are getting the correct value(true) loading the selected date in   getInstancc() of EntityHome., 
Once the page is loaded the value is no more available in EntityHome.

When we tried to update(any operation) data we are not getting the the selected instance which is loaded while page is loading ane it is giving new Instance with primary key as null. Since the selected instance is not available in getInstance() it is treating as a new entry and not updating the existing entry.

The below are the configurations in components.xml

```
<persistence:managed-persistence-context auto-create="true"
name="entityManager"
persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/projectEntityManagerFactory" />
```

In persistence.xml

```
 <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
value="java:/projectEntityManagerFactory" /> 
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"  
 value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
```

I am suspecting this issue is due to migrating the seam version.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: O/T (maybe not)... Wildfly 8.2 contains Mojarra 2.2.7, so why 'upgrade' to 2.1? (and 2.1 is an api, not a version) Seam is dead, why not migrated to CDI? Wildfly contains CDI 1.2... It als contains Hibernate 4.3.7, so why 'upgraded' to 4.0.1 (why not use JPA?). Most likely only because of the Seam stuff if I'm right... hmmmmm....

Comment: @kukeltje Since we are using Seam 2.3.1, which will not support JSF 2.2.7 we are using JSF 2.1x. Though seam is dead we want to run our application on WildFly with less changes and impect, so we decided to go with seam 2.3.1. We are using JPA in our project which I didn't mentioned in the post..Even I am suspecting this is related to Seam.

Comment: Ok, but now you are 'upgrading' a legacy application to a new application that is from the start already a new legacy application... If I were CTO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. Earlier we are using JSF 2.1.29, now I downgraded my JSF to 2.1.7 which is inbuilt provided by Seam 2.3.1.